# Twitter-Like Scrolling Title

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, twitter, uiscrollview

On the Twitter iOS app when you scroll past your name in the profile section below the navigation bar, your name begins to scroll into view on the navigation bar itself and sticks there if you scroll further down.

I'm wondering how to go about implementing a similar effect and what the best method would be.
It looks as if:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Might be a good bet, but not entirely sure how to make it scroll into view rather than simply animating it when reaching a particular top offset.

I'm using a custom header view rather than the UINavigationBar, so doesn't need to be specific to that, but would work best with a UILabel.

Would prefer Objective-C but Swift is welcome.

Lovely example image:
[image: Twitter Header]

Comment: To give you an idea, you basically need to add the contentOffest to your navtitle instead of checking for a certain offset.

Comment: So updating the frame of the UILabel used for the title as you scroll?

Comment: Hi.I want to do the same thing with every new section of table view. when section row 0 pass under the navigation bar the title would update tile twitter.

Comment: @Alex it may be quite late but here is the full implementation http://www.thinkandbuild.it/implementing-the-twitter-ios-app-ui/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here I got it working. This ViewController is presented in a simple `UINavigationController`.

```
@interface ViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    UIScrollView *titleView;
    UIScrollView *contentView;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

    [self setTitle:@"My Title"];

    titleView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 44.0)];
    [titleView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0.0, 88.0)];
    [self.view addSubview:contentView];

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, CGRectGetWidth(titleView.frame), 44.0)];
    [titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0]];
    [titleLabel setText:self.title];
    [titleView addSubview:titleLabel];


    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;


    contentView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [contentView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(0.0, 4000.0)];
    [contentView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:contentView];

    UILabel *contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), 44.0)];
    [contentLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [contentLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0]];
    [contentLabel setText:self.title];
    [contentView addSubview:contentLabel];
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, MIN(scrollView.contentOffset.y + 64.0, 44.0));
    [titleView setContentOffset:contentOffset];
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi.I want to do the same thing with every new section of table view. when section row 0 pass under the navigation bar the title would update tile twitter

Comment: Nice and easy, just check for the current section in the `scrollViewDidScroll:` then set the title to the section title and it should work fine.

Comment: Great example, but how would it work if you weren't using the navigation bar. As per the image above i'm using a custom view to act as the bar in order to obtain the same blurred image effect as Twitter. I'm guessing a UIView in replacement of the view used for the title would work?

Comment: Yea instead of adding the titleView to your navBar simply add it whereever you'd like in another view. The goal is just to have two ScrollViews and pass that contentoffset. The 64 points was an offset for the navbar, so just set that to the height of you view so it lines up properly

Comment: It would be the same in Swift. Just remove the square brackets.

Comment: Apparently, this is causing a crash... When I push a view controller onto the navigation stack, it works fine... it scrolls and updates the UINavigationBar currently... But when it animates onto the UINavigationBar and I pop the view controller, it crashes. Not sure why but basically implementing the delegate method 'scrollViewDidScroll' crashes the app when I pop the controller. Also, it just crashes with nothing to log...

Comment: Apparently your solution works without crashes... but Instead of a content view of UIScrollView i use a UITableView.... they both conform to a uiscrollviewdelegate though... so idk why this crash is occuring

Comment: Solved the crash by implementing `scrollRectToVisible:animated` which scrolls the UITableView. I set the UITableView to scroll to the top of its content in `viewDidDisappear` and now theres no more crashes... It only crashes when the animation is taking place... Maybe there might be another solution?

Comment: @RyanPoolos what about the way the profile section becomes the nav bar? any idea on that?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but I'd suggest a new question for it. If you link it here I can give it a go

Comment: there is a library for this, but i cannot find it. where is it at?

Comment: No idea. I have never used a library for it because its so easy to do on my own. If the code above has stopped working let me know.

Comment: This is a great simple example, pretty straight forward. I am stuck though trying to get this to work with a tableview cell that uses self-sizing cells and the label is embedded in a stack view inside the cell. If anyone can point me in the right direction, let me know.

Comment: That is definitely a lot of layers to the complexity haha. Short of you starting a new questions on SO, you might try messing with `willDisplayCell` delegate method for tableView to know when to start listening for the cell. And also using `UIView.convertRect` to convert the label's frame to the view's frame coordinate system for your math around the `titleView.contentOffset`.

Answer (score 8):

the code above is good, clear and simple for scrolling of title only.

but if you want to make a view same as Twitter, you can use this tutorial:

http://www.thinkandbuild.it/implementing-the-twitter-ios-app-ui/

this tutorial is implemented in swift.

you can download the source code by clicking on button "Download Source" in end of this tutorial.

or go directly to github:
https://github.com/ariok/TB_TwitterUI

**below we will explain how implement the fuction scrollViewDidScroll:**

1- These are the first lines for the scrollViewDidScroll function:

```
var offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
var avatarTransform = CATransform3DIdentity
var headerTransform = CATransform3DIdentity
```

Here we get the current vertical offset and we initialize two transformations that we are going to setup later on with this function.

2- manage the Pull Down action

```
if offset < 0 {

     let headerScaleFactor:CGFloat = -(offset) / header.bounds.height
     let headerSizevariation = ((header.bounds.height * (1.0 + headerScaleFactor)) - header.bounds.height)/2.0
     headerTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(headerTransform, 0, headerSizevariation, 0)
     headerTransform = CATransform3DScale(headerTransform, 1.0 + headerScaleFactor, 1.0 + headerScaleFactor, 0)

     header.layer.transform = headerTransform
}
```

3- manage the scroll up/down

```
else{
  // Header -----------

   headerTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(headerTransform, 0, max(-offset_HeaderStop, -offset), 0)

//  ------------ Label

   let labelTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, max(-distance_W_LabelHeader, offset_B_LabelHeader - offset), 0)
            headerLabel.layer.transform = labelTransform

//  ------------ Blur

   headerBlurImageView?.alpha = min (1.0, (offset - offset_B_LabelHeader)/distance_W_LabelHeader)

// Avatar -----------

   let avatarScaleFactor = (min(offset_HeaderStop, offset)) / avatarImage.bounds.height / 1.4 // Slow down the animation
   let avatarSizeVariation = ((avatarImage.bounds.height * (1.0 + avatarScaleFactor)) - avatarImage.bounds.height) / 2.0
   avatarTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(avatarTransform, 0, avatarSizeVariation, 0)
   avatarTransform = CATransform3DScale(avatarTransform, 1.0 - avatarScaleFactor, 1.0 - avatarScaleFactor, 0)

   if offset <= offset_HeaderStop {

      if avatarImage.layer.zPosition < header.layer.zPosition{
                    header.layer.zPosition = 0
                }

      }else {
        if avatarImage.layer.zPosition >= header.layer.zPosition{
                    header.layer.zPosition = 2
                }
            }}
```

4- Apply Transformations

```
header.layer.transform = headerTransform
avatarImage.layer.transform = avatarTransform
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me.

Comment: How does this change with the new iPhone X format?!

Comment: Where in the code does the 'text' move from the 'Profile' view into the 'Header' view?!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the Code Ryan, It works fine in my project. The code has a little mistakes but I fixed it and here is the version in Swift in case anybody need it.

```
    self.title = "My Title"
    titleView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 44.0))
    titleView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0.0, 88.0)
    self.view.addSubview(titleView)

    var titleLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, CGRectGetWidth(titleView.frame), 44.0))
    titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 17)
    titleLabel.text = self.title
    titleView.addSubview(titleLabel)

    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView

    contentView = UIScrollView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    contentView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0.0, 4000.0)
    contentView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(contentView)

    var contentLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), 44.0))
    contentLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    contentLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 17)
    contentLabel.text = self.title
    contentView.addSubview(contentLabel)

override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){

    var contentnOffset:CGPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, min(scrollView.contentOffset.y + 64.0, 44.0))
    titleView.setContentOffset(contentnOffset, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It was lagging a little bit for me. all I had to do is set the animated attribute in the setContentOffset to false.

Comment: Where in the code does the 'text' move from the 'Profile' view into the 'Header' view?!