# How to implement searchbar for UITableView with parallax effect like in Safari on iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parallax, effect

First of all I tried a lot of controls from cocoacontrols website - at best they hide the header but show it when the scrollview (or table, or webview) is scrolled up as far as top (zero offset).

`UINavigationItem` with its `hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling` works via the same way.

So how to implement this behaviour in my own application?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237757/twitter-like-scrolling-title

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is in scope, but have you tried using a webview?

If all you are concerned with is having a parallax effect, why not use a webview to contain your data and use CSS to give you the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks for your try but the logic for this screen is already implemented and it will be at least hard to reimplement it with webview